# Multiple Windows CMD

Tags: c++, c, windows, cmd

I'm working on a grader using `cmd`.

I want to know if can I allocate another `cmd` while one is running.

I want to use the `cmd` to measure the time that a process use and if the time exceed the time limit, terminate it.

Comment: Why do you need two console windows for that? Anyway, you can only have one, as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944(v=vs.85).aspx). For a timer, you can use something like `SetTimer` and have the callback call `std::exit`.

Comment: This seems like an AB question, you want to know A, but ask about B. Your real question is: `How do I automatically terminate a process after a certain time in Windows?`, right?

Comment: What do you mean "using `cmd`"? If you write a c/c++ program, you compile it with gcc/visual studio and you get an output executable which does not involve `cmd`.

Comment: @us2012 do you mean [XY Problem as shown on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @AlvinWong My grader doesn't compile. Just check the output from the exe

Comment: @Xuicide does this answer my comment or are you just telling me random things?

Comment: @us2012 Can I do it from inside a c++ application?

Comment: @Xuicide, I mentioned one possibility.

Comment: @AlvinWong I did mean the XY problem, although I think that not too much of the meaning is lost by changing the letters. Good idea to provide the link, though.

Answer (score 0):

To start a new cmd window you can do:

```
cmd.exe /c yourprogram.exe
```

Also you can use

```
start yourprogram.exe
```

Both will create a new cmd.exe and run your program. Second one (start) will create cmd if your program is a console application, otherwise it will just run it.

Answer (score 0):

Since this isn't moving along very quickly, I'll just give a standard way of exiting after n milliseconds. It can easily be changed to any time unit by making it a template functor instead (see the declaration of `sleep_for` for what I mean) and supplying it with a `std::chrono` unit.

```
int main() {
   std::thread waiter([](unsigned long long milliseconds) {
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(milliseconds));
      std::exit(0);
   }, 5000);

   int i{};
   while (1) {
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
      std::cout << i++ << '\n';
   }
}
```

First, I make a thread with a procedure that accepts a number of milliseconds and start it by passing 5000ms. I put in the parameter for the ease of transition to the aforementioned functor. It sleeps for that long and then exits the program. Meanwhile, the main thread just outputs a count every second.

For a demo, [see here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/Fn3XQ%240). Here's the output:

> 0
>   1
>   2
>   3